# add rel="nofollow" to Specific link by jquery or php in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nofollow

i want add **rel="nofollow"** to Specific link(site.com) in wordpress site by **php** or **jquery**

thank you

Comment: what's the purpose of adding it client-side?

Comment: i m showing third party ads in my site by javascript  for seo i have to add rel=nofollow to exist link in my source

Comment: it is unlikely that making changes to this on the client side will have the desired effect, as robots are pretty limited in what client-side stuff they run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this jquery

```
$(function(){ 
$('a[href^="http://example.com/external/link"]').attr('rel','nofollow');
})
```

Comment: Your jQuery code works well
I know that Google can crawl JavaScript right now, but to be more confident I can use PHP? How?

Comment: Dont know about php man guess this should work fine i am a dotnet dev

Comment: Thanks for the guide